# XPATH remove attribute

Tags: xpath

Hi does anyone know hwo to remove an attrbute using xpath.  In particular the rel attribute and its text from a link.  i.e. `<a href='http://google.com' rel='some text'>Link</a>`  and i want to remove rel='some text'.

There will be multiple links in the html i am parsing.

Answer (score 5):

You can *select* items using xpath, but that's all it can do - it is a query language.

You need to use XSLT or an XML parser in order to remove attributes/elements.

Comment: Can you please give some examples? or a reference link?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Oded, Xpath merely identifies XML nodes. To remove/edit XML, you need some additional tooling.

One solution is the [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)-based plugin [XMLTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) (disclaimer - I wrote this). It provides a simple mechanism to read an XML file, identify parts of that using XPath, and change it (including [removing nodes](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/#usage.remove)).

e.g.

```
<remove path="web/servlet/context[@id='redundant']"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried using Javascript for this If that is applicable in your scenario:-

```
var allLinks=document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++)
{
allLinks[i].removeAttribute("rel");
}
```